# Displaying an image in php

Tags: php, mysql

how to display blank if there is no image in a record.As i have inserted a record in database without an image but while fetching an record it is displaying an blank image in front end.It should not show any image if there is no image.Here is my code. If there is no image it should show only description.

Blogimage.php

```
<tbody>
<?php include "blogs.php" ;
while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($result))
{?>            
<tr>    
<td><img src="admin/upload/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" height="100" style="width:60%;height:50%;"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo "<p style='width:60%;'>" .$row['blog_description']."</p>"; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</tbody>
```

Blogs.php

```
$id=$_GET['title'];
$res = "SELECT *  FROM blogs 
 WHERE blog_title='$id'";
 $result=mysql_query($res);
```

Comment: How to hide the image field if there is no image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing this

```
<img src="admin/upload/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" height="100" style="width:60%;height:50%;"/>
```

to this

```
<?php if($row['image']) echo "<img src='admin/upload/".$row['image']."' height='100' style='width:60%;height:50%;' />"; ?>
```

Comment: how can we insert hypen instaead of spaces into database

Comment: How to separate Url text with hypens

Answer (score 0):

A couple of general points before we go into this

1) The MySql library you are using is old and busted - you should be using something newer - [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) - the options are [Mysql PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and [MySqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) - **I promise you, you will be glad you did**, i use [IDIORM](https://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as an interface and find it very good (Also helps prevent stuff in point 2 below!)

2) Your code can be SQL injected - [more about that here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) - this is very bad :)

Below is an example, I have fixed the SQL injection problem, and put in some logic that would test to see if there is an image, if not, it will dump out a 'noimage.jpg' src value.

I have removed the include, and just simply put the code for blogs.php inline.

```
<tbody>

    <?php 

    //START CODE FOR BLOGS.PHP
    $query = sprintf("SELECT *  FROM blogs WHERE blog_title='%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']));
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    //END CODE FOR BLOGS.PHP

    while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        if(!empty($row['image']) && strlen($row['image']) > 4)
        {
            $iamgeSrc = 'admin/upload/' . $row['image'];
        }
        else
        {
            $imageSrc = 'admin/upload/noimage.jpg';
        }
    ?>            
        <tr>    
            <td>
                <img src="<?php echo $imageSrc; ?>" height="100" style="width:60%;height:50%;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo "<p style='width:60%;'>" .$row['blog_description']."</p>"; ?>
                </td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>

</tbody>
```

If you want no image to show at all, then this would work

```
<tbody>

    <?php 

    //START CODE FOR BLOGS.PHP
    $query = sprintf("SELECT *  FROM blogs WHERE blog_title='%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']));
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    //END CODE FOR BLOGS.PHP

    while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $image = '';

        if(!empty($row['image']) && strlen($row['image']) > 4)
        {
            $image = '<img src="admin/upload/'.$row['image'].'" height="100" style="width:60%;height:50%;"/>';
        }

    ?>            
        <tr>    
            <td>
                <?php echo $image; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo "<p style='width:60%;'>" .$row['blog_description']."</p>"; ?>
                </td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>

</tbody>
```